# How I can fix this problem with Google Docs API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I write this script in React Component to include Google Docs in iframe.
I try everything. Nothing works. I dont know how to fix this. Its my first time in working with Google Docs API.

```
const Files = () => {
    const loadGoogleDocsApi = () => {
        window.gapi.load('client', () => {
            window.gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: 'api'
            }).then(() => {
                // Создание встроенного окна Google Docs
                const docUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/DOCUMENT_ID/edit';
                const docId = 'doc';
                const docName = 'Document Name';

                const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.src = `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${docId}/pub?embedded=true`;
                iframe.title = docName;
                iframe.width = '100%';
                iframe.height = '600';
                document.getElementById('google-docs-container').appendChild(iframe);
            });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Асинхронная загрузка скрипта API
        const loadScript = async () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = 'https://www.google.com/js/api.js';
                script.onload = resolve;
                script.onerror = reject;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            });
        };

        // Загрузка скрипта API и выполнение loadGoogleDocsApi() после его загрузки
        loadScript()
            .then(() => {
                loadGoogleDocsApi();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Ошибка загрузки скрипта API:', error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Google Docs</h1>
            <div id="google-docs-container"></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Files;
```

```
So I have Errors:
Files.jsx:32 GET https://www.google.com/js/api.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
Files.jsx:42  Ошибка загрузки скрипта API: Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: script, currentTarget: script, eventPhase: 2, …}
(анонимный) @ Files.jsx:42
Promise.catch (асинхронно)
(анонимный) @ Files.jsx:40
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(анонимный) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Files.jsx:42  Ошибка загрузки скрипта API: Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: script, currentTarget: script, eventPhase: 2, …}
```

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.